# Choosing a Composition of n and then choosing a Composition of each of its components

Tags: combinatorics

I'm working through Stanley's enumerative combinatorics textbook and am stuck on the following problem:

Fix $ n \in \mathbb{P}$. In how many ways (as a function of n) can one choose a composition $\alpha$ of $n$, and then choose a composition of each part of $\alpha$.

My approach was to use that there are $2^{n-1}$ compositions of $n$, and then the composition is $n=a_1+...+a_k$ so that I can pick $2^{a_i-1}$ compositions for each one, so that I have a total of 2^{2n-(k+1)} compositions.

The only thing is that I have this k inside of my function which is independent of n.

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: What is a "composition" of $n$? EDIT : Found that it is a way of writing $n$ as the sum of a sequence of strictly positive integers, order included.

Comment: A composition of a positive integer n is defined as writing n as the sum of positive integers $a_1+...+a_k$, where the order matters.